# Split varying list of file paths into all folders and file names

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of a few hundred text file paths varying in number of folders.

e.g. C:/user/folder/subfolder/filename.docx

I need to split these into the file name and folders. I used to do this by using excel functions "FIND", "LEN", "RIGHT" etc. but this only worked if all paths have the same number of folders which is currently not the case.

How might I complete this in VBA? My VBA knowledge is minimal but with this being such a common task, there should be a script out there somewhere that completes this?

I have searched the web, but it is hard to find a script that completes this.

Any help whatsoever would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the text to columns feature within Excel? Why does this need VBA?

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513). SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I was really asking if anyone knew of a script out there that completes this. But yes I agree with you, this does appear like a code-writing question. I will remember that for next time.

Comment: Learning to write your own code, stumbling and bumping, will teach you something and add to your arsenal of tools. Copy-pasting random code from random strangers on the Internet isn't going to teach you anything. Give a man a fish...

Comment: @tigeravatar that worked perfectly! I can't believe I didn't come across this while researching. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mat'sMug You are 100% right. I will avoid these type of questions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted a VBA approach, something like the following would work:

```
   Dim fso As FileSystemObject
   Dim path As String
   Dim folder As String
   Dim file As String

   path = "C:/user/folder/subfolder/filename.docx"
   Set fso = New FileSystemObject
   folder = fso.GetParentFolderName(path)
   file = fso.GetFileName(path)
```